# Define Excel variable in Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to iterate through column A, starting from row 3, and debug.print the values of all the populated cells.

I can't define a variable as range. I think the problem is that I'm using Excel VBA in an Outlook VBA IDE.

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim enviro As String
    Dim strPath As String

    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

    'the path of the workbook
    strPath = enviro & "\Documents\test1.xlsx"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        bXStarted = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Open the workbook to input the data
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Process the message record
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer

    RowCount = 3

    For Each rw In xlSheet.Rows
        Debug.Print xlSheet.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value
    Exit For

    RowCount = RowCount + 1

Next rw

xlWB.Close 1
If bXStarted Then
    xlApp.Quit
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, have you added a reference to the Excel library? (In Tools>References) Where do you get the error when debugging?

Comment: I think I solved the problem. I had to dim rw as Object, not Range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that rw was supposed to be defined as Object, instead of Range.